# Necesito comprimir JPG antes de subir imagen a firebase

Tags: android, firebase

mi pregunta es sobre  una app que estoy creando , tengo un sistema de carga de imagen que funciona de bien, pero las imagenes pesan mucho, eh visto muchas soluciones ,pero no puedo implementarlas a mi codigo. la idea es que las imagenes sea de 640x480 y pensen menos de 100kb.

Este codigo lo eh visto muchas veces pero no puedo implementarlo.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, 100, out);
```

Aqui les paso mi codigo con el que subo las imagenes con firebase al servidor storage

```
public class nuevaCategoria extends AppCompatActivity {


Button elige, subir;

private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ImageView img_vieja;
private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 71;
private Uri filePath;


FirebaseStorage storage;
private StorageReference storageReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nueva_categoria);

    //Firebase Init
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageReference = storage.getReference();
    //init view
    elige = findViewById(R.id.btn_elige_foto);
    subir = findViewById(R.id.btn_subir_foto);

    img_vieja = findViewById(R.id.img_vieja);


    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    //inicio elige

    elige.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            metodoeligefoto();
        }
    });
    //fin elige

    // inicio subir
    subir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            uploadImage();
        }
    });
    // fin subir

}//fin oncreate!

Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap (100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

private void uploadImage() {
    if (filePath != null) {

        String stringUri = filePath.toString();
        String fileName = stringUri;

        //COMPRIMIENDO..



        //COMPRIMIENDO...

        //PROBANDO ACHICADOR..
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Subiendo Imagen...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ref.putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(nuevaCategoria.this, "Imagen Cargada 100%..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(nuevaCategoria.this, "Error al cargar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando :  " + (int) progress + " %");
                    }
                });
    }//fin del if upload image...!


}

private void metodoeligefoto() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona foto"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
//START--

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK &&
            data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();


        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            img_vieja.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

//END--
```

}

La imagen se sube perfecto. pero pesa mucho. saludos y gracias. casi termino mi app y me falta esto

Comment: Prueba con https://tinypng.com/

Comment: Necesito que lo haga dentro de la app. en android studio

Comment: Por eso!, tienen una API Web pero es de paga por volumen. Tienes 500 gratis

Comment: esta bueno pero necesito algo que sea gratis , como ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, baos);
            final byte[] foto = baos.toByteArray(); pero nose como usarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar usando este metodo en el ActivityForResult

```
    public static File saveImageOnDirectory(File fileImage, File folderDir) {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss_SSS").format(new Date());
            File _file = new File(folderDir, timeStamp + ".jpg");

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = ImageMaganer.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(fileImage.getAbsolutePath(), 640, 480);
                FileOutputStream _writer = new FileOutputStream(_file.getPath());
                _writer.write(toByteArray(bitmap, 80));
                _writer.close();
                bitmap.recycle();
                return _file;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }


public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String Path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Path, options);
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Path, options);
    }


public static int calculateInSampleSize(Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        int height = options.outHeight;
        int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;
        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            int halfHeight = height / 2;

            for(int halfWidth = width / 2; halfHeight / inSampleSize > reqHeight && halfWidth / inSampleSize > reqWidth; inSampleSize *= 2) {
                ;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

El metodo guarda la imagen en un nuevo directorio con 640x480 y a 80% de calidad las imagenes las transforma a pesar entre 50kb o menos

Comment: si pero como lo aplico en mi codigo? yo necesito que al final me retorne una uri para poder pasarlo a firebase y subirlo.

Comment: Como mencione en el inicio solo debes llamar el metodo en el onActivityForResult y guardar la imagen comprimida en otro lado.

Comment: ImageMaganer y toByteArray , no me los deja importar. Me marca error.

Comment: Agregue los metodos que faltaban para que puedas probar

Answer (score -1):

Lo solucione usando el plugin ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper y zetbaitsu/Compressor. imagenes de cualquier peso las redimensionar a 15kb cada foto. la mejor solucion.

Comment: Podrías compartir un extracto de como te quedo para comprimir?